# How to use search for & replace custom HTML tags in Java?

Tags: java, json, regex

Am using Java 1.7...

Have the following JSON response (from a JSON array) which contains different tags (one containing photos and the other containing videos):

```
{
    "articles": 
    [
        {
            "htmlBody": "<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"4806ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899ad\"></asset-entity>\r\nAngelie Jolie was seen at Wholefoods with ex-beau Brad Pitt.\r\n
                         <asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"4806fe7d-c175-c380-4ab2-dda068b42b033cbf\"></asset-entity>\r\n- The majority of their kids were with them.\r\n<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"35064086-5d85-1866-4afc-a523c04c2b3e42a6\">
                         </asset-entity>\r\n"
        },                      
        {
            "htmlBody": "<asset-entity type=\"video\" id=\"48906fe30-8dx6-7e04-4b18-98c4d77176eaz412\"></asset-entity>\r\n
                        Reese Witherspoon was spotted at the Paris airport\n\nRumor is that she arrived for the filming of her new movie\n\n <asset-entity type=\"video\" id=\"4207182e-cgga-4e0a-4b97-a5ec0aa619c33b42\"></asset-entity>\r\n"
        },
        {
            "htmlBody": "<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"350686a2-6fef-9fd7-445d-b2888fa56c3454da\"></asset-entity>\r\nMatt Damon was seen walking to StarBucks for a quick latte and chocalate danish while in Boston.\r\nHere's a video clip of him kindly greeting the paparazzi:<asset-entity type=\"video\" id=\"2507f140-ed4c-7e1b-4f44-8c57e051409d6fea\"></asset-entity>\r\n"
        }
   ]
}
```

In my Java code, it htmlBody is a String...

Questions:

1. Can anyone provide me a good regex query (using Java) to parse:

and:

```
<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"48906fe30-8dx6-7e04-4b18-98c4d77176eaz412\"></asset-entity>
```

Wish to extract the id from either photo or video and store into a data structure (e.g. a HashMap) but need to be able to find a mechanism which will search the String based htmlBody in my code for either photo and video using regex.

Once I have the ids stored in the correct data structure:

e.g.

```
Map<String> videoTags = new HashMap();
Map<String> photoTags = new HashMap();
```

Then, I can replace these tags with the actual  (or the equivalent one for  containing the actual assets.

2. Is a HashMap the best way to store these specific asset ids (with the intent or replacing them with a hardcoded URL of the actual asset)?

Any suggestions regarding the regex or design would be mostly appreciated... If regex is not a viable solution to search for specific custom HTML tags (as a String) in Java, what else (in terms of techniques) could I use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Tim - So you are saying there's no other way to search for these two different custom HTML tags other than using regex? Thanks for the response.

Comment: if the length of the id is the same why not just find the index of the "id" then extract it

Comment: Issam - I need to know if it belongs to video or photo - that's the issue? After extracting where would I place the data (e.g. data structure)?

Comment: I am not sure how you came to that conclusion. That is not at all what I'm saying, in fact I only shared a link, the answer in that link says **not** to use regex to process html.

Comment: @Tim - this is a custom HTML tag - if not use regex what other (open source libs or coding techniques) I can use to search and replace these type of HTML tags (which are inside a Java String)? Thanks for responding.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover i will help you with that

Comment: if you really need a regex for that *asset line*, here as Java String: `"<asset-entity\\s+type=\\\\\"(photo|video)\\\\\"\\s+id=\\\\\"([^\"]+)\\\\\">\\s*</asset-entity>"` - `group(1)` is photo or video, `group(2)` the id - but doesn't consider that you can have extra spaces or line-breaks, character, different order of values, or ... **Parsing would be much more indicated!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse your html (by any attribute, tag etc). Here's an example using Jsoup [selectors](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
String html = "<asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"4806ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899ad\">"
  + "</asset-entity>\r\nAngelie Jolie was seen at Wholefoods with ex-beau Brad Pitt.\r\n <asset-entity type=\"photo\" id=\"4806fe7d-c175-c380-4ab2-dda068b42b033cbf\">"
  + "</asset-entity>\r\n- The majority of their kids were with them.\r\n<asset-entity type=\"video\" id=\"35064086-5d85-1866-4afc-a523c04c2b3e42a6\"> </asset-entity>\r\n";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("asset-entity[type=photo]");
for (Element element : elements) {
  String type = element.attributes().get("type");
  String id = element.attributes().get("id");
  System.out.println(type + " " + id);
}
```

**output**

```
photo 4806ad76-7433-fs34-50d1-b12bdbc308899ad
photo 4806fe7d-c175-c380-4ab2-dda068b42b033cbf
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! One last question, how to use JSoup to replace <asset entity type = "photo"/> with <img src/> inside the exact place (inline) where the <asset tag/>?